# SOQL query activities same as in Account

Tags: soql

I would like to know on how to query all activities sames as on Account that it show all activities (Task, Event and Email) even through those activities related Contact/Opp not directly to Account.

Answer (score 0):

for events

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Events) FROM Account
```

for tasks

```
SELECT (SELECT Id FROM Tasks) FROM Account
```

Answer (score -1):

when you will write query for events and task . these two related to contact so we will write query for contacts and will use condition as contact's accountId has to be same as account id of particular account

for example :
we have an account name XYZ and that account id is '0016F00002OVbTQ'

So now query will be :
**Select Id, Account.Name, Name, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Tasks), (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Events) from Contact where AccountId = '0016F00002OVbTQ'**

I hope above solution will be .